# Basement pipe inside wall leaks slowly onto floor

Tags: plumbing

I have a basement pipe that leaks onto my basement floor. It's leaking very slowly. It could be clogged and needs to be cleaned out? There is a concrete wall surrounding the pipe. The house was built with a clamp over it with nuts so water wouldn't leak out of the pipe. I figure that's where the hole is to clean out the pipe.

Years ago the pipe flood the basement. My grandpa had to drain the pipe out to stop the leak and a lot of black water started pouring out of it. He removed the clamp and cleaned the pipe out but was a mess.

He was able to stop the leak and this was over 40 years ago when it happened. Now it started leaking again but just slowly. It looks like the concrete on the floor is leaking because when the water leaks out in the basement it's coming from the bottom of the pipe in the wall shown in this photo. But the concrete area is only wet. The entire pipe is completely dry. I am thinking this pipe is a drain pipe or sewer pipe that is clogged and the water is nowhere to flow so it's leaking out on the floor now.

Can you please tell me if I have to shut the water supply off before draining this pipe out?

I also want to know if I can seal the concrete on the bottom of the pipe with QuikCrete? I was going to use [this product](https://www.lowes.com/pd/QUIKRETE-10-lbs-Hydraulic-Water-Stop-Cement/3012639?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-bdm-_-ggl-_-LIA_BDM_210_Concrete-Block-_-3012639-_-0-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8JbEg_SY9AIVCI6zCh37JQCrEAQYAyABEgLe9PD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to seal the concrete around the pipe into the floor.

I don't have money to spend replacing this pipe. So any idea to stop this leak would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: is the pipe metal?  it looks like cast iron.  i've never seen a clean out with bolts like that.  If I had to guess that is your sewer stack.  generally unless you have control over all occupants in the house you'd shut off the water so someone doesn't flush a toilet and have it all come down on you while you are servicing.

Comment: I'm confused by your description. You say the _concrete_ is leaking. What does that mean? How can it be wet if the pipe is dry? You have to figure out what's actually leaking before trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the bolts were maybe what Grandpa put in, to hold something over the old leak. I'd be taking it off, then consider finding some pastic pipe which will fit into the old cast iron(?) pipe. Cut the latter,maybe a good few inches off it, and push the former up, then down, into the cast iron.It will go below the leak, and stop that, then you'll need to seal the upper join. Obviously total replacement is the real solution, this is, literally, a stopgap.

It looks like clear water, not sewerage, which has a distinctive colour and odour, and is probably not under mains pressure. However, as with any unsure - turn mains off anyway. Concrete covering the leak will only be temporary, leakage will still happen, then you'll have extra work digging it all out again.

Answer (score 1):

Sewer pipes were often cast iron, likely what you have. You will not stop a leak from the outside of the pipe. Photo does not show but it may be a joint. Traditional joints are bell and spigot with oakum and lead packing. It is reasonably easy to tighten the packing by tamping it down, I have done it myself. If it is not leaking joint, refer to answer one.